# Reflow with Heat Gun - WLCSP

Tags: reflow

I need to solder a WLCSP chip ([FAN3852](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FAN3852-D.PDF)) to a [DIP breakout board](https://www.digikey.jp/products/en?keywords=WLCSP%20breakout).

Since the WLCSP chip already has tiny solder balls, would it be possible to hold the chip in place on the breakout board with tape and then heat it with a heat gun? I'd have to monitor the surface temperature to ensure it doesn't exceed the max reflow tolerance (~260C).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T75VzHjnExc

Comment: That's quite unlikely to go well.  Stranger things have happened, but you'd want a hot air rework tool not a "heat gun".  If you had to improvise some sort of heat from below like a hot plate (before soldering the header pins) might work better.  Also, there are services which will mount things on breakouts, they've been mentioned here in the past.

Comment: google `sand soldering`

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured that using a heat gun was kind of a redneck approach... Sand Soldering looks super cool! As it turns out, I have a spare IH lying around that I can use. I've never used a PCB assembly service before - any recommended online retailers for manufacturing this simple standalone WLCSP-6 to DIP-6 breakout?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes. Keep in mind its harder if you have other parts already on the board (use foil as a heat blocker). And the small size vs the heat gun's diameter and air flow speed. I've done it on a similar wlp chip using a small butane soldering iron with the heat gun option. About the diameter of a AA battery.

But overall its not a good way to do it. And especially not an easy way to do multiple at a time or repeatedly. There are other solutions you could try like a toaster oven converted for soldering or a pan etc etc but if you need to do multiple a proper hot air soldering station is used.

Alternatively, you can solder to it dead bug style. A 6 pin WLP like that is easy (relatively) to solder to with some spare wire as there would be no overlapping. Still not a walk in the park though. http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2012/11/15/fine-pitch-bga-deadbug-soldering/

Comment: I contemplated doing "dead bug" soldering, but honestly I would be terrible at it (tried my hand at 28-TSSOP once, didn't go well...). Might be worthwhile to invest in the toaster oven or sand soldering method.

Comment: A recent one i saw used a clothes iron. Looked like they added some extra parts like temperature control but very cool. But considering how many you may need a cheap dollar store or thrift store pan and some sand is all you need for a quick board or two.